# Is using a property files a safe option?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties-file

I  have a requirement to use property files to have some important information which should not be revealed to anyone.

My question is : regarding security concern, is using a property file a safe option or not ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this topic before you continue any further: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: It's only safe if the file is not readable by anyone.

Comment: how can I ensure that it's not readable by anyone after deploying my project ? Normally i will create a javaresource folder in my project for it.

Comment: If a file is not readable by anyone it is not readable by your program,  and thus not useful.

Comment: You may  encrypt sensitive data in your properties files
http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html and https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+Use+Jasypt+to+encrypt+passwords+in+configuration+files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on a larger context (security policy of the whole solution) and the nature of data you want to keep secure.

In most environments, a secure network is constructed by using firewalls etc., and inside, even sensitive information (like API keys) are stored in property files etc. as plain text. There are more sophisticated solutions that can keep these information encrypted, but it requires considerable setup.

Some people suggest embedding a encryption key in the source to encrypt the property files and then obfuscating the source to hide the encryption key, but this is security through obscurity and should be avoided.

If you are storing password information to authenticate users etc., then you should store salted hash of passwords.

**EDIT**:
Probably one of the best way would be to encrypt the property file and let operators type the encryption keys every time the app. starts (to avoid storing the encryption key in a persistent store). Note however, an attacker could still read the process memory to get the decrypted value.
This is why most solutions focus on securing the network, rather than protecting against an attacker who already has access to the servers.

Comment: I am not stroing password information in it, but still its critical information

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices:

1. read properties value from system properties configured only in the operating system of the deployment server
2. read properties value by lookin up JNDI name, so your properties value are configured in the application server

With each of the above approaches security concerns can be addressed focusing on the deployment environment and not focusing on the application sources or binary.

Comment: Can you just tell me more details about your first approach?

Comment: @user3713995 Set an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) than [read it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)

Comment: Environment variable will create environment dependency.. not a good  practice

Comment: @user3713995 Generally speaking I agree with you, but in such case you want environment dependency because you want your server environment be the place where to focus security efforts on. You might reduce environment coupling adopting convention over configuration principle: convention (`System.getenv`, if property is not found then get it from JNDI name) configuration (whatever you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

Ask back. There are two options: a configuration inside the application, and outside the application, in the Java EE server. I think they meant to have the properties file outside the application. You should ask that.

Having it outside the application also allows deploying the app in different environments. And is more secure as even the developer does not need to store somewhere the production password.

How to access the file depends a bit on the server.